# Entity framework 4.0 strange with saving data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I faced with the next problem. I have a data warehouse with model

```
public class GameResult
    {
        public int GameResultId { get; set; }

        public virtual Competition Competition { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomDate DateGame { get; set; }       
        public virtual Contender ContenderFirst { get; set; }
        public virtual Contender ContenderSecond { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}



public class Competition
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //Lazy loading
        public virtual KindSport KindSport { get; set; }


    }
```

Something like that
I generate some data for fact table `GameResult`

```
gameResult.Location = location;
gameResult.Competition = competition;
gameResult.ContenderFirst = firstContender;
gameResult.ContenderSecond = secondContender;

public void saveGameResult(GameResult gameResult)
        {
            using (var db = new GameContext())
            {
                db.GameResults.Add(gameResult);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```

But when I try to save data get that I don't save enity just in fact table they getting cascade saved also in child tables as `Location, Contender`.

How I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` marks the whole object graph as `Added`.

This is a way to fix it:

```
public void saveGameResult(GameResult gameResult, .... more arguments ....)
{
    using (var db = new GameContext())
    {
        db.GameResults.Add(gameResult);
        gameResult.Location = location;
        gameResult.Competition = competition;
        gameResult.ContenderFirst = firstContender;
        gameResult.ContenderSecond = secondContender;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But then you have to add more arguments.

A more tedious way is to leave everything the way it is and mark each dimension as `UnChanged`:

```
db.GameResults.Add(gameResult);
Entry(gameResult.Location).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
...
```

Yet another way is to set the `Id` values only:

```
gameResult.LocationId = location.LocationId;
... etc.

public void saveGameResult(GameResult gameResult)
{
    ... (original code)
```

But then of course the primitive Id properties should be part of he fact class, forming [foreign key assocations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/05/07/foreign-key-association-in-entity-framework-4.aspx).

Comment: In first case I get `A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation.dll`

Comment: Well, it's just to give an idea. I can't control dependencies with `Microsoft.Office`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to load the entities Location and Contender from the DB. Otherwise they will be inserted in it.

Comment: I should generate child entities for example `Location location = locations[random.Next(countLocations)];`

Comment: `List<Location> locations = selectLocations();
            int countLocations = locations.Count();` select from db