# How to link to items in a database and not creating the same item again

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, local-database

I am just a beginning programmer in C#, MVC4, razor and Linq. Now I was busy trying to build an application for an non-existing Hotel. And the application works almost how it is suppose to. But there is one minor error. When I create a booking I want to link a Room and a list<> of Guests to the booking. But every time when I create a new booking there is a new Room created in the database where everything is the same except for the id. And for the Guests it is the same, if I create a new booking the guests are also created in the database and not linked to the Booking. I have used the debugger and the object Room and the list is perfectly passed to the Create of the Booking. So it must be going wrong in my Create method of the Booking. I am not able to find out what is wrong with my Create method. So I was hoping to find some help over here. Any help would be appreciated.

Other information:
TempStore is a static class where I save some of my variables temporary.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Booking booking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TempStore.tempGuests.Count == 0 || TempStore.tempRoom == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("NoGuestsSelected", "Please select the persons for your room.");
                ModelState.AddModelError("NoRoomSelected", "Please select a room for your booking.");
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                booking.Room = TempStore.tempRoom;
                booking.Guests = TempStore.tempGuests;
                booking.PriceTotal = TempStore.priceTotal;
                booking.AveragePrice = TempStore.averagePrice;
                booking.StartDate = TempStore.startDate;
                booking.EndDate = TempStore.endDate;

                db.Bookings.Add(booking);
                db.SaveChanges();

                //Clearing the TempStore cause everything has been added
                TempStore.tempGuests.Clear();
                TempStore.tempRoom = null;

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(booking);
    }
```

This is my TempStore

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Hotel.Models
{
    public static class TempStore
    {
        public static Room tempRoom;
        public static ICollection<Guest> tempGuests = new List<Guest>();
        public static DateTime startDate;
        public static DateTime endDate;
        public static decimal priceTotal;
        public static decimal averagePrice;
    }
}
```

This is where I set my Guests

```
    public ActionResult AddGuest(int id)
    {
        Guest g = db.Guests.Find(id);

        if (TempStore.tempGuests.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (Guest gue in TempStore.tempGuests)
            {
                if (gue == g)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("DuplicateGuest", "Cannot select the same guest twice.");
                    return RedirectToAction("SelectGuest");
                }
            }
        }

        TempStore.tempGuests.Add(g);

        return RedirectToAction("SelectGuest");
    }
```

This is where I set the room for the booking:

```
    public ActionResult AddRoom(int id)
    {
        Room r = db.Rooms.Find(id);
        TempStore.tempRoom = r;
        return RedirectToAction("SelectGuest");
    }
```

Comment: Is the error that there are duplicate rooms being created? Also, need more information. What are the properties of Booking?  What is TempStore?

Comment: I think the issue is how TempStore is creating the room. Can you post the TempStore code please?

Comment: @user1666620: The error is that there are duplicated rooms created and duplicated users. Booking does not contain any properties.

Comment: @RufusL I Posted my TempStore like you asked.

Comment: I must be missing something. Nothing is populating the TempStore.Room property? Is this line: `booking.Room = TempStore.tempRoom;` equivalent to: `booking.Room = null;`?

Comment: @RufusL I wanted to prevent that my post was going to be to long. So it would be to much code and nobody want to take a look at it. But now I added also my addGuest and addRoom method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework 4.0 strange with saving data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855661/entity-framework-4-0-strange-with-saving-data)

Comment: This is a really bad use of a static class and properties. What if 2 users are creating a booking at the same time? Why do you not have one single form where you create the booking, assign the room and add the guests.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know it is not the right way of doing it. But it is my first time programming in C#, Razor and ASP.net. So I do not know how to do it better. I tried to find other solutions but I was not able to come up with them. Anyway, I solved my own question the improved create method is standing below in Answers.

Comment: There is only ever one 'instance' of a static property so if User1 sets the value, then User2 in the meantime is also creating a booking form that sets the value, User1's data is lost and they will be saving incorrect data. At the very least, use `Session` to store the data, but ding all this in a single form rather than multiple forms would be a far better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be not in a neat way. But my problem is solved. I would like to thank everybody for their help.

This is how I solved it:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Booking booking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TempStore.tempGuests.Count == 0 || TempStore.tempRoom == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("NoGuestsSelected", "Please select the persons for your room.");
                ModelState.AddModelError("NoRoomSelected", "Please select a room for your booking.");
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                booking.PriceTotal = TempStore.priceTotal;
                booking.AveragePrice = TempStore.averagePrice;
                booking.StartDate = TempStore.startDate;
                booking.EndDate = TempStore.endDate;

                db.Bookings.Add(booking);
                db.SaveChanges();

                booking.Guests = new List<Guest>();

                foreach(Guest g in TempStore.tempGuests)
                {
                    db.Bookings.Find(booking.Id).Guests.Add(db.Guests.Find(g.Id));
                }

                db.Bookings.Find(booking.Id).Room = db.Rooms.Find(TempStore.tempRoom.Id);
                db.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                //Clearing the TempStore cause everything has been added
                TempStore.tempGuests.Clear();
                TempStore.tempRoom = null;

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(booking);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you have to have some way to determine that it's a duplicate.  That'll depend on your data model, but if you have fields that you know will be unique, you can search for a matching record before saving the new one.

Comment: it was not a duplicate everything in Tempstore was the same as in my database. After I added them to the database the id changed. But now I solved my problem see my answer below if you are still interested in what was wrong.